# Can't get script to run for all users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Alright, so I've been writing a doc recently and noticed a road block that I ran into. I can run the script fine but when I create another Incognito tab to test permissions of the other users, it doesn't run the script. I cannot access the *Script Editor* (Tools > Script Editor) either when in this incognito so it's not a option to apply this manually by the user whenever somebody is added to the document.

Can somebody please help  me further, my code.

```
function onEdit(){

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = s.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && range.getColumnIndex() == 4 && (range.getValue().toLowerCase() == "x"))
    s.hideRows(range.getRowIndex(),1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try clearing your cache? Sounds weird but I had to do that and log out of email first. Then it worked fine.

Sean.